# Is there a library than can convert ounces into Cups?

Tags: units-of-measurement

Ideally I could specify something like 10 as my input (in ounces) and get back a string like this: "1 & 1/4 cups". Is there a library that can do something like this? (note: I am totally fine with the rounding implicit in something like this).

Note: I would prefer a C library, but I am OK with solutions for nearly any language as I can probably find appropriate bindings.

Comment: I would definitely consider asking for a specific programming language.......

Comment: Is this really so complicated that you need an external library? I mean, all you do is divide by eight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really two things: 1) the data encompassing the conversion, 2) the presentation of the conversion.

The second is user choice: If you want fractions, you need to write or get a fractions library. There are many.

The first is fairly easy. The vast majority of conversions are just a factor. Usually you will organize known factors into a conversion into the appropriate SI unit for that type of conversion (volume, length, area, density, etc.)

Your data then looks something like this:

```
A   acres   4.046870000000000E+03   6
A   ares    1.000000000000000E+02   15
A   barns   1.000000000000000E-28   15
A   centiares   1.000000000000000E+00   15
A   darcys  9.869230000000000E-13   6
A   doors   9.290340000000000E+24   6
A   ferrados    7.168458781362010E-01   6
A   hectares    1.000000000000000E+04   15
A   labors  7.168625518000000E+05   6
A   Rhode Island    3.144260000000000E+09   4
A   sections    2.590000000000000E+06   6
A   sheds   1.000000000000000E-48   15
A   square centimeters  1.000000000000000E-04   15
A   square chains (Gunter's or surveyor's)  4.046860000000000E+02   6
A   square chains (Ramsden's)   9.290304000000000E+02   5
A   square feet 9.290340000000000E-02   6
A   square inches   6.451600000000000E-04   15
A   square kilometers   1.000000000000000E+06   15
A   square links (Gunter's or surveyor's)   4.046900000000000E-02   5
A   square meters (SI)  1.000000000000000E+00   15
A   square miles (statute)  2.590000000000000E+06   7
A   square millimeter   1.000000000000000E-06   15
A   square mils 6.451610000000000E-10   5
A   square perches  2.529300000000000E+01   5
A   square poles    2.529300000000000E+01   5
A   square rods 2.529300000000000E+01   5
A   square yards    8.361270000000000E-01   6
A   townships   9.324009324009320E+07   5
```

In each case, these are area conversions into the SI unit for area -- square meters. Then make a second conversion into the the desired conversion. The third number there is significant digits.

Keep a file of these for the desired factors and then you can convert from any area to any area that you have data on. Repeat for other categories of conversion (Volume, Power, Length, Weight, etc etc etc)

Answer (score 1):

My thoughts were using Google Calculator for this task if you want generic conversions...

Example: http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?q=10%20ounces%20to%20cups -- returns JSON, but I believe you can specify format.

Here's a Java example for currency conversion:
http://blog.caplin.com/2011/01/06/simple-currency-conversion-using-google-calculator-and-java/

Answer (score 1):

Well, for a quick and dirty solution you could always have it run [GNU Units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/) as an external program. If your software is GPL compatible you can even rip off the code from Units and use it in your program.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out JSR 363, the Units of Measurement Standard for Java: http://unitsofmeasurement.github.io/

At least in C++ you get basic support via "value types" already, but you still have to implement those conversions yourself or find a suitable library similar to what JSR 363 offers for Java.